# From $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ construct the Klein bottle

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, klein-bottle

The argument by Wikipedia is enough or complete for the solution of the exercise?

> **Exercise:** From $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ construct the topological space known as Klein bottle.

Wikipedia says

...More formally, the Klein bottle is the quotient space described as the square $[0,1] × [0,1]$ with sides identified by the relations $(0, y) \sim (1, y)$ for $0 ≤ y ≤ 1$ and $(x, 0)\sim  (1 − x, 1)$ for $0 ≤ x ≤ 1.$

Comment: I am quite lost here I also thought about drawing the construction of the klein bottle. I don't know maybe I need to do mathematical things.

Comment: What do you mean "enough or complete"?

Comment: @TrevorGunn well I was expecting something like a proof, and not just a description about the klein bottle. Maybe it's already a proof :) idk

Comment: Proof of what exactly?

Comment: @TrevorGunn A proof about the construction from the square to the klein bottle, things related to homeomorphism maybe?

Comment: @TrevorGunn Do you think the argument from Wikipedia it's a good answer?

Comment: Do you mean you want a proof that [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Surface_of_Klein_bottle_with_traced_line.svg) is the same as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Klein_Bottle_Folding_1.svg)? That would require a formal definition of the former. On the other hand, the latter does have a formal definition and it is exactly what you've quoted.

Comment: If you want to prove that Wikipedia's construction is the same as a Klein bottle, you'd have to start with a definition of a Klein bottle other than the Wikipedia construction.

Comment: @TrevorGunn Since my professor didn't give me the formal definition of the former, I don't think that's the way to solution this exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that answer looks just fine as I see it. But if you want more detail, you can extend on the idea given by Wikipedia. I will call $[0,1]=I$ for short.

We start with the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]=I^2$. We define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on it, the one generated by $(0,y)∼(1,y)$ for $0≤y≤1$ and $(x,0)∼(1−x,1)$ for $0≤x≤1$ (verify it is an equivalence relation).

Let $g:I^2\rightarrow I^2/\sim$ be the canonical quotient map, and give $I^2/\sim$ the quotient topology with respect to $g$. Geometrically you are identifying or "gluing" the sides of the square as follows:

[image]

You then have a completely defined topological space (the Klein bottle) built from the square $I^2$.

Comment: How is $g$ given or defined? I mean how is the map of $g$?

Comment: $g(x,y)$ is the equivalence class of $(x,y)$ under the equivalence relation $\sim$ previously defined. I use the notation: $g(x,y)=[(x,y)]$.

Comment: This construction is usually given as the definition of the Klein bottle. It would be useful if you say what is the definition you want to work with in your question. Or maybe your professor just wanted you to formalize the idea of gluing the sides of the square we all know, using the notions of topological quotient.

Comment: Yes maybe just to formalize. Why to give the quotient topology?

Comment: The quotient topology makes the identified point to be the same in the quotient, and makes close points to them to be close as well in the quotient. Imagine you live in that space; you are standing at $(0, 1/2)$ and you walk across the segment $(x, 1/2)$. Once you reach $(1, 1/2)$ you are in fact right where you started, for these two points are the same in this world. The quotient topology also made that path continuous.

Comment: I see, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You take the unit square and identify opposite sides to get a cylinder.  Then go to identify the two circles at the opposite ends of the cylinder, like you were going to make a donut (torus), but, twist one of the circles $180^0$ before identifying...